# How to get current user and display its information on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Below is my database structure

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMxU2.png)

I have created a recyclerView in an activity to show all the bookings made by users. The recycler View works fine but the problem is that it shows all the details of bookings made by every user. I want to only display Bookings made by the current logged In user.Below is the Main Acitivity

```
public class ViewBooking extends Fragment {

FirebaseDatabase mdatabase;
DatabaseReference refbooking;

RecyclerView recycler_booking;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Booking, BookingViewHolder> madpter;

String userEmail;
FirebaseUser user;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_booking, null);

    mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userEmail = user.getEmail();

    recycler_booking=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.BookingRecyclerView);
    recycler_booking.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler_booking.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    onStart();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Query query = mdatabase.getReference("Bookings").orderByChild("userEmail").equalTo(userEmail);
    madpter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Booking, BookingViewHolder>(Booking.class, R.layout.viewbooking_layout, BookingViewHolder.class, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BookingViewHolder viewHolder, Booking model, int position) {
            viewHolder.bookedplace.setText(model.getNameOfPlace());
            viewHolder.bookedplace.setText(model.getNameOfPlace());
            viewHolder.bookedslot.setText(model.getSlotnumber());
            viewHolder.bookeddate.setText(model.getCurrentDate());
            viewHolder.bookedduration.setText(model.getDuration());
            viewHolder.bookedstarttime.setText(model.getStartTime());

        }

    };
    recycler_booking.setAdapter(madpter);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("View Booking");
}
}
```

I have created a String userEmail that gets current users email Id through Auth

The code works fine without query and displays all the bookings. But nothing is displayed on the recycler view after i add the query

Answer (score 0):

You are missing listeners:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    madpter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    madpter.stopListening();
}
```